# Setting cookie expiry time using javascript

Tags: javascript, cookies

I have some javascript on my website that loads a modal on a specific page. It uses a cookie to determine whether someone has seen the modal. I need to set an expiry date/time for this but don't know how. I've checked on here for answers but can't see anything that helps me with the code I've got.

Can anyone help? I thought the '365' in the code specified the no. of days for the cookie to expire but it's expiring when the browser session ends.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
     if ($.cookie('MyCIEH_popup') == null) {
         $('#modalLarge').modal('show');
         $.cookie('MyCIEH_popup', '365;');
     }
 });
</script>
```

Comment: The age of a cookie is not measured in days! See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie#write_a_new_cookie.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace `$.cookie('MyCIEH_popup', '365;');` with:

```
$.cookie('MyCIEH_popup', 'value', { expires: 365 });
```

Note: It's probably a better solution to use native js for that, see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/cookies/set).

Comment: Thank you very much! That works. Do you know if I can specify a date and time at which the cookie expires?

Comment: That works using native js, linked in the answer.
just set `expirationDate` to a unix timestamp.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help!